# When copying data to another table, parent_id issue in Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I am using Laravel + MySQL.

I have following three tables:

```
templates table
id
name

template_pages table
id
template_id
parent_id
name
content


user_pages table
id
user_id
parent_id
name
content
```

When user picks one template, it will get pages from `template_pages` table.

Here, I want to create the new records to `user_pages` table.

I could get `pages rows` from `template_pages` table with `template_id` which user picked.

But when I insert them to user_pages table, parent_id wasn't match as I expected.

One user can get several same templates.

Please help me how I can solve this issue.

Thank you

---

EDIT for controller and model.

template model has hasMany pages.

Here is my controller:

```
foreach($template->pages as $page)
{
  $newpage = new UserPage();
  $newpage->user_id = auth()->user()->id;
  $newpage->parent_id = $page->parent_id; // I think this is wrong.
  $newpage->name = $page->name;
  $newpage->content = $page->content;
  $newpage->save();
}
enter code here
```

Comment: Can you show us your Model and Controller code?

Comment: @Enver I just edited. Thank you!

Comment: Check if `$page` contains any data first, And Post the error you are getting,  your relation may be wrong or you have no pages related to this template.

Comment: well, No error message. Just need to change parent_id.  `$page->parent_id` is `pages` table's id. I think I can't use that as same for `user_pages` table too. so what is solution for this?

Comment: Hi @Enver, please check my following answer.

Comment: Hi @Makdous, please check my following answer.

Comment: Does your `UserPage` model `$fillable` array contain `parent_id` property?

Comment: Yes, of course.

Answer (score 0):

I did like this.

```
$pageArray = [];
foreach($template->pages as $page)
{
   $newpage = new UserPage();
   $newpage->user_id = auth()->user()->id;
   $newpage->parent_id = $page->parent_id; // I think this is wrong.
   $newpage->name = $page->name;
   $newpage->content = $page->content;
   $newpage->save();
   $pageArray[$page->id] = $newpage->id;
}
foreach($pageArray as $key=>$pageId)
{
  $page = UserPage::find($pageId);
  $page->parent_id = $page->parent_id===0? 0:$pageArray[$page->parent_id]; //parent_id=0 means root page.
  $page->save();
}
```

It worked well for me.
But is there any better solution?